# Django: 404 URL not found when linking to a new url via the homepage

Tags: python, django

so I'm new to Django and have been having an issue adding a new page to my website.

The home page and blog detail page are working fine. The issue arises when I try to link to an "About me" page.

These are the relevant setting I have as of now:

blog/urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('about/', views.AuthorDetail.as_view(), name='about'),
]
```

blog/views.py

```
class PostList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'index.html'

class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

class AuthorDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'about.html'
```

where 'about.html' is currently just a 'Hello World' html output.

In the directory above I have, 
app/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls'))
]
```

Lastly, in the html of the homepage I have the following link,

```
<a class="nav-link text-white font-weight-bold" href="{% url 'about' %}" >About Author</a>
```

As I said, the homepage (url: /) and post detail (url: slug) work fine. But when I try to go to the url localhost:8000/about/ I get an error saying

Page not found (404)

Request Method:     GET

Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/about/

Raised by:  blog.views.PostDetail

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: your about page is hitting your `PostDetail` url instead of the `about` url. We can see this because the error was raised by `PostDetail`. Django is treating it as a slug and matching it with the second url instead of the third. My lazy way to work around this is by adding something like `post/` before the slug in your second url pattern.

Comment: Ahhhh I see!! I saw that PostDetail was raising the error but couldn't figure out for the life of me why that was. What you said makes great sense. Thank you.